# How to hide content in screenshot, screenshot should appear black?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

i don't want to disable screenshot for my activity instead want them to be hidden.
Using getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE), user cant take screenshot. But i want to enable user taking screenshot, instead contents will be hidden

Comment: Or someone could just use a camera and take a picture of the screen...

Comment: You should have very good reasons to do something like this. As a user I hate when basic common functionality like screenshots or copy and paste is not available for "security" reasons.

Comment: yes i have content copyright issue so cant allow screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is impossible.
You can check if `onPause()` is called when you capture the screenshot.